# pdf scrolling to a page bug? in firefox pdf viewer

Tags: javascript, firefox, pdf.js

hello I'm developing a Firefox extension. i stuck on a problem .basically my extension should remember the last page i was reading and should scroll to that page to when i open it again.
well almost done.

the problem Firefox show page number exactly on top `page` field correctly but it really doesn't scroll to that page.if i scroll small amount i can see page number is actually lot lower than the actual page it shows.after i scroll it shows actual page on page filed(top bar). look at page box in top bar.in this example i set page `700` to load and it load and show page 700 on page number box .but actual page is `460`.

this GIF will show exactly

[image]

how do i scroll to a specific page

1) using `#page=pagenumber` end of the url 
this works but have above problem.so i try another way/second way.

2) directly call  `PDFViewerApplication.page=pagenum;` . i found what is the method that related to set the current page.

unexpectedly second one also has same problem .so i take a sample ,page number i set to scroll and real page number it shows.

```
page i want | page actually it scroll to 

700         |        460
692         |        453
163         |        107
```

and if i set page number to 700 (i'm testing on a specific pdf .it has 741 total pages.) viewer shows page 460 and it's not a random.it always show 460.but when i manually type a page viewer correctly show that page.and this problem doesn't occur always but about 70% times problem occurred.

why is this happening ?

> update

above problem can reproduce in following way.

open a pdf

scroll manually to specific page ex-200

refresh the page

now firefox will open the pdf and page number text box will show number 200 as page number.

scroll bit..you will see number text box value change to very different value even if you scroll to next page .

Comment: If you do this, could you also make it possible to open the same pdf file in different tabs. This is useful when one has links and wants to switch to different pages many times, e.g. look at the bibliography pages or the table of content.
cf. [here](http://superuser.com/questions/58384/open-the-same-pdf-multiple-times)

Comment: @user39158 umm what i don't get it.could you clarify for me?

Comment: When I read wikipedia i often open links in new tabs, altough it could be the same article. I would like to do the same for pdf books. It actually often happens to me when I want to check the references, then I have to go back the the page I was reading. I would like to click Ctrl + link and then have the same pdf file opened at the linked page but in another tab